# How to auto submit form based on time

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I generate a question paper. I want to auto submit the question paper when time reaches its maximum.

I generate the timer using java script and call`document.forms["form1"].submit`method, but its not submitting, it will refresh the page when time finished.

Comment: specifically your <form> tag

Comment: This may be successfully submitting the form. Depending on your code (which we'll definitely need to see), this could be expected behavior.

Comment: i have aspx form in that i have Question and radio buttons and i want to submit there values automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Form:

```
<form id='myform'>
```

JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function(){document.forms["myform"].submit();},3000);
```

Comment: setTimeout fits this problem better as it's a one time call

Comment: Sorry it was mistake :) Edited.